# How to make uiwebview youtube video in landscape orientation when viewcontroller in portrait

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using embedded youtube in my UIWebView , my viewcontroller is in portrait mode but I am unable to see the video in fullscreen landscape . I tried many solutions from Stackoverflow , but none are working on iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a similar problem to yours, what I did was:

1. Even though it's portrait only, you can get the device
       orientation.
2. If the orientation is landscape, you can transform the status bar by rotating, and same thing with the MPMoviePlayerController.

Here's my code I used (it's for iOS6 though, so it might be different

```
-(void) receivedRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    //Using this part to find the view controller on top (the one that's showing the video in fullscreen).

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    //After a little testing, the class of that controller is MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController
    if ([topController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController")]) {
        topController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

        //The 20 and -20 are to prevent the movie from going over the status bar
        topController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width,self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.height - 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work since you've done no effort to understand what you have to do. You should learn how to debug a project (for in this case, I'm 100% sure you didn't even look if this function is being executed or not)

Comment: No. You should add rotation gesture notification recogniser.

Comment: thanx @LordZsolt NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController") worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}

-(void) receivedRotate: (NSNotification*) notification
{


        UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        //Using this part to find the view controller on top (the one that's showing the video in fullscreen).

        while (topController.presentedViewController) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController;
        }



        if ([topController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"AVFullScreenViewController")]) {

            switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) {
                case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
                    NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp");
                    break;
                case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
                    NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown");
                    break;
                case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                    NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft");
                    topController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
                    break;
                case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                    NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight");
                    topController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


            topController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
        }

}
```